# Filtered search return duplicates after the first search

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

In my angularJS web-app I've this piece of code where I show some names (forming part of the array SearchRcps) filtered by a searchString inserted in an input search bar. I do this `$index%4==0` to distribute the results on several rows of 4 columns each. When I make the first search, the result is correct, but when I comeback to empty searchstring or when I make a second search, there are shown duplicates.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row" ng-repeat="rcpGroup in SearchRcps | filter:searchString track by $index" ng-if="$index%4==0">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="rcp in (SearchRcps | filter:searchString).slice($parent.$index,$parent.$index+4)">
                            <p>{{rcp.name}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>
```

Anyone

Comment: are all the values duplicated ? or only some of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `ng-if="$index%4==0"` clause from the row div to a separeted div:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="rcpGroup in SearchRcps | filter:searchString track by $index">
         <div ng-if="$index%4==0">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="rcp in (SearchRcps | filter:searchString).slice($parent.$index,$parent.$index+4)">
                     <p>{{rcp.name}}</p>
              </div>
         </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All you need is a little logic ;)